# My pie chart (chartJs) does not appear

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

i have a small problem with chart js

I want to draw a pie graph, but the page remains empty when I referch it

my code is as follows, I have doubts with online src of script tag :

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>C.H.A.R.T.JS</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.2.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<script>
$(function()
{
//$('body').css({'background':'red'});
var ctx = $("#myChart").get(0).getContext("2d");

var data = [
    {
     value :270,
     color :'Dodgerblue',
     heightLight: 'Lightskyblue',
     label :'Imed1'
    },
    {
     value :50,
     color :'Red',
     heightLight: 'Lightskyblue',
     label :'Imed2'
    },
    {
     value :40,
     color :'yellow',
     heightLight: 'Lightskyblue',
     label :'Imed3'
    }
    ];
var pieChart = new Chart(ctx).Pie(data);
}); // fin jQuery


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your data structure are use chartJS1, but your CDN is chartJS2.
that's why you got only error msg.

```
var ctx = $("#myChart").get(0).getContext("2d");

var data = {
    labels: [
        "Red",
        "Blue",
        "Yellow"
    ],
    datasets: [
        {
            data: [300, 50, 100],
            backgroundColor: [
                "#FF6384",
                "#4BC0C0",
                "#FFCE56"
            ],
            label: 'My dataset'
        }]
};
var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx,{
    type: 'pie',
    data: data,
});
```

Comment: but how can i make it smaller ? it is too big ... 
CSS ?

Comment: @user5080818 you can control whether it is responsive or not with `options: { responsive: false }`.  You can pass that in like this `data: data, options: {responsive: false}`.   It's responsive by default filling it's parent container.  You could set a parent container with a max-width or predefined width/height. Or you could do something like `#myChart {max-width: 400px;}`.  With max-width it will stay responsive if the parent container is goes smaller.

Answer (score 2):

Try creating the chart with this structure shown in the docs.

Looks like your structure is a little off based on the docs. 
http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#doughnut-pie-chart

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

// For a pie chart
var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx,{
    type: 'pie',
    data: data,
    options: options
});`

var data = {
    labels: [
        "Red",
        "Blue",
        "Yellow"
    ],
    datasets: [
        {
            data: [300, 50, 100],
            backgroundColor: [
                "#FF6384",
                "#36A2EB",
                "#FFCE56"
            ],
            hoverBackgroundColor: [
                "#FF6384",
                "#36A2EB",
                "#FFCE56"
            ]
        }]
};
```

It's responsive by default, expanding to it's parents container. You can set a parent container max-width or the canvas itself, which will keep it responsive for smaller screens.

```
<style type="text/css">
    #myChart {
        max-width: 400;
    }
</style>
```

Or if you do not want it responsive at all you could set that option to false.

```
options: {responsive: false}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering 
I will follow your link ... thank you

Comment: once again thank you ... 
for css I had to add px to 400 to make it work
but i prefere this one : options: {responsive: false}